Derivative and limit of a two-variable function
Let $f(x, y) = \begin{cases} 
      xy\sqrt{-\ln(x^2 + y^2)} & 0 < x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\\
      0 & (x, y) = (0,0)
   \end{cases}$. Find $f'_x$ and $f'_y$ then compute the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}f'_x(x,y)$.
My attempt: The derivative is not hard and I got $f'_x = \frac{-y((x^2 + y^2)\ln(x^2 + y^2) + x^2)}{(x^2 + y^2)\sqrt{-\ln(x^2 + y^2)}}$ after some transformations. Doing a polar coordinates substitution with $x = r\cos\phi$ and $y = r\sin\phi$ I get to $f'_x = \frac{-r\sin\phi(\ln(r^2) + \cos^2\phi)}{\sqrt{-\ln(r^2)}}$. Then the limit $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$ becomes $r\rightarrow 0$ and I end up with $$\lim_{r\rightarrow0}\frac{-r\sin\phi(\ln(r^2) + \cos^2\phi)}{\sqrt{-\ln(r^2)}} =\\
=\lim_{r\rightarrow0}\frac{-r\sin\phi(r^2 - 1 + \cos^2\phi)}{\sqrt{1-r^2}} =\\
=\lim_{r\rightarrow0} -r\sin\phi(r^2 - \sin^2\phi) =\\ =\lim_{r\rightarrow0} r\sin^3\phi = 0$$
Is this correct? In particular I am worried about the function being defined differently at $(0,0)$ and I not too sure how (if at all) it affects the derivative when it approaches that point in the limit.

How did $\ln(r^2)$ become $r^2-1$? To your question, the function's value at a point does not affect its limit.

@JulioPuerta $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x} = 1$. They're equivalent as $x$ goes to $0$

Not at all. $\ln(r^2)$ tends to $-\infty$ and $r^2-1$ tends to $-1$.

@JulioPuerta yes you're right $r^2 - 1$ goes to $-1$ not $0$ so the equivalence isn't true.

I think it's doable using l'Hopital
